# error in sending mail in java using springFramework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

this is my code for sending a mail to a user.

```
mailMessage=new SimpleMailMessage();
        Strinf passwoed="Abij@1"
        String emailHeader = "Dear,";
        String emailFooter= "Thanks & Regards ";
        mailMessage.setFrom("admin@hcl.com");
        mailMessage.setTo("user@hcl.com");
        mailMessage.setSubject("Email For Password");   
        mailMessage.setText(emailHeader + " \n EMAIL: " + this.newUserModel.getEmailId()+ "\n PASSWORD : " + passWord+ "\n " + emailFooter );
        try {
            mailSender.send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("exception is :"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

When i am running this code i got a exception is :null message..

Comment: does stacktace gives anything?

Comment: try{
            this.mailSender.send(mailMessage);
        }

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao :stackgives me only line no where the exception occcurs..and the exception occurs at try block gives null exception...

Comment: bcoz of U did not set up MailSender

Comment: @iKishore :same exception occurs..

Comment: @Sam :I have only declare mailSender.Can't get it did not set up mailSender?

Comment: okay...u have set it in smtp ?

Comment: @Sam:No.. How to set it in smtp?

Comment: if [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As Per You Ask on SO:-When i am running this code i got a exception is :null message

Just Configure a bean file i.e one xml file.

```
<bean id="mailID" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="put host server name that u want to use" />
    <property name="port" value="port_No" />
    <property name="username" value="u_name" />
    <property name="password" value="u_pwd" />

    <property name="properties_name">
       <props>
              //define Ur key Here
           </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myMailID" class="Ur Main Class Name following the packageName">
    <property name="prop_Name" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
```

Here is a good [Tut](http://www.zend2.com/bu.php?u=OqlfJ09yz5Jg2AKG0QNFTLuBgLIpF4v7qim2yO2pVfxy6H1wS//Rb9TGLxGQehFFei4A/YQLke1I%2b9k0C2SqU24DYWYSLWAtnr14C/z3j5pzGA9xdw==&b=29&f=norefer)

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem thanks all of you...
I added the following code in my applicationcontext.xml as per sams..and my code running very well.
Following is my code...

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host">
            <value>203.90.70.245(here is the host name)</value>
        </property>
        <property name="protocol">
            <value>smtp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="port">
            <value>2525</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>vijayk@gmail.com(eamil id from you want to send)</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>1234(password of your email id)</value>
        </property>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.host">203.90.70.245</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.from">vijayk@gmail.com</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and remove from the code  `mailMessage.setFrom("admin@hcl.com");` 
And written this code in serviceLayer.